# Insert and Edit Template show in Devexpress in aspxGridview

Tags: c#

In Insert Mode I want to show one kind of Template and Edit Mode I want to show another Kind of Template in Devexpress Control in C#.NET

Answer (score 3):

This can be implemented using the following approach:

You should define the EditFormTemplate so that it contains a different set of editors for the Insert and Edit functionality. Handle the HtmlRowCreated event to hide non required editors based on the ASPxGridView's IsNewRowEditing property value.

Check out the [sample project](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/GetSCAttachment.ashx?id=6e21cca2-58c7-4db9-8ae3-afdaa72d3425) on this [issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q145990.aspx) which demonstrates the solution based on user controls and binding expressions. In this solution, the EditForm template contains two user controls with the Visible property bound to the ASPxGridView.IsNewRowEditing property:

[HTML]

```
<uc1:Edit id="Edit1" runat="server" Visible="<%# !Container.Grid.IsNewRowEditing %>"></uc1:Edit>
<uc2:Insert id="Insert1" runat="server" Visible="<%# Container.Grid.IsNewRowEditing %>"></uc2:Insert>
```

Btw, this [issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q251847.aspx) might also be helpful. If you need more help, please contact the DevExpress support team [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question).

Answer (score 0):

Use an ASP template field and individual item templates inside your gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField id="test" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          test
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox Text="test" runat="server"/>
      </EditItemTemplate>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I did the above from memory. Heres a link to an example i found as well:
http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-GridView-Edit-ItemTemplate-Mode.aspx

Comment: No,Really I want to see it in Devexpress ASPxGridview Control

Comment: In Insert Mode I want to show one kind of Template and Edit Mode I want to show another Kind of Template in Devexpress aspxGridview Control in C#.NET

Comment: Hi, does my approach in the answer above using the usercontrols work for you? Please try it. If you need more help then please contact our support team: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question