# Edit Template and Insert Template in Devexpress aspxgridview.How it Possible?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Edit Template and Insert Template in Devexpress aspxgridview.How it Possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert and Edit Template show in Devexpress in aspxGridview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151208/insert-and-edit-template-show-in-devexpress-in-aspxgridview)

Answer (score 0):

We've posted a sample project showing how this can be done at:

[Different template for insert and edit](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q145990.aspx)